# Is it possible to implement n stacks using 4 queues?

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

i know how to implement stack using one or two queues, but how about n stacks using only 4 queues?
is it possible at all? if it is would you please explain the algorithm?thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Assuming you can implement a stack from 2 queues (as your question states), the "4 queues" is now just noise, and if you can implement n stacks using 2 stacks, the answer to your question is yes.

This can be done by pushing to the stack not only the element, but the stack's id as well. When popping, you push elements to the other stack, until you find element from required stack, and then return them back.

This can probably be optimized to avoid pushing all the way back over and over again, but I believe worst case complexity is still linear in the number of elements.

Here is a (very unoptimized) pseudo code.

```
Pop(stack_number):
  element = null
  while not head_stack.empty():
    if head_stack.peek()[0] == stack_number:
      element = head_stack.pop()
      break
    else:
      other_stack.push(head_stack.pop())
  while not other_stack.empty():
    head_stack.push(other_stack.pop())
  return element

Push(stack_number, element):
  head_stack.push({stack_number, element})
```